# batch script to display from n to m lines from a text file and save a new text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have found code (see below) but I do not have the ability to encode. I want to select the desired part (lines) from text file and save in another text file! Thank you for all your help!

CODE:

```
@echo OFF
:: Get the number of lines in the file
set LINES=0
for /f "delims==" %%I in (data.txt) do (
set /a LINES=LINES+1
)

:: Print the last 10 lines
set /a LINES=LINES-10
more +%LINES% < data.txt
```

Comment: `more +%LINES% < data.txt > newfile.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Note** The following reflects your question body and code content only ignoring your question title text.

Here's a script which will do what your question code does except it outputs to a file.

The output file will be written to the current directory and be named, **Name**-Last**X.ext**. *Where **Name** and **.ext** will match the same name and extension as your source file and **X** will be the number of lines of output.*

The only changes you would ever need to make would be to the source file on line 3 and the last number of lines to output on line 4.

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "SrcFile=data.txt"
Set "LastNum=10"

Rem If SrcFile doesn't exist or LastNum isn't at least 1 exit the script
If Not Exist "%SrcFile%" Exit/B
If 1%LastNum% Lss 11 Exit/B

Rem Calculate line number for first line of output
Set "#=-%LastNum%"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Find /V /C ""^<"%SrcFile%"') Do Set/A #+=%%A

Rem Re-calculation for files with less lines than LastNum
If %#% Lss 0 Set/A "LastNum+=#, #=0"

Rem Create destination filename for output
For %%A In ("%SrcFile%") Do Set "$=%%~nA-Last%LastNum%%%~xA"

Rem Output to destination file
More +%#% "%SrcFile%">"%$%"
```

*Note that `More` will change <kbd>tab</kbd>s to a sequence of <kbd>space</kbd>s*

Comment: Hi Compo! Thanks so much. It was very good, but it does not help me a lot! Please help me! I have masa text files that I have to edit. I want to take the number of required lines (from n to m) from a text file and save to other text file. Text files contain some other special characters! I've checked this code (findstr /R /N "^" data.txt) that shows the number of lines in the text file. I MUST start from the beginning of text file (line 0). For example. Save text from 0 to 4 lines, then from 9 to 14 lines, etc. Please help me! I am very grateful for all your help!

Comment: The emboldened **Note** at the top of my answer said it all. Here you write your own code and we help you fix issues with it. I fixed the code you provided. If you want help with a different scenario, then you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46773629/edit) providing the code you've created to accept, parse and attempt to output the information you want. This isn't a free code request site where you provide a list of specifications and we churn out a solution for you.